# difference between web services clients results in one error(AXIS) in one success(JAXWS)

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, tomcat6

difference between  web services clients results in one error in one success
I have web service I build using JAXWS 2.2 on tomcat , based on wsdl .
Based on this wsdl I created client that works great .
But when I getting web services from external client im getting errors on server ,  I sniffed the network , and I saw there are differences 
But I don’t know how critical they are mostly namespaces , as I see from sniffin the external request I see they used AXIS to build the client .
For the tomcat exception im getting , I know according to the logs on the server side it gets to the service but fails in one of the stubs methods
Here is my client service that works:

```
POST /console/ws/APIEndpoint HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://foo.com/ServerApi/sendMessageRequest"
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.5-b01 
Host: 192.168.3.69:18112
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1221

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns3:sendMessage xmlns:ns2="http://www.foo.com" xmlns:ns3="http://www.foo.com/">
<NP_MESSAGE>
<ns2:HEADER>
<REQUEST_ID>NPAABBYYMMDDXXXXXZZZZ</REQUEST_ID>
<PROCESS_TYPE>PORT</PROCESS_TYPE>
<MSG_TYPE>Publish</MSG_TYPE>
<TRX_NO>MI000004548992</TRX_NO>
<VERSION_NO>1</VERSION_NO>
<RETRY_NO>2</RETRY_NO>
<RETRY_DATE>2011-11-03T11:48:23.769+02:00</RETRY_DATE>
<FROM>MI</FROM>
<TO>aa</TO>
</ns2:HEADER>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</NP_MESSAGE>
</ns3:sendMessage>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

and now this is the request from external client that doesn't work:

```
POST /console/ws/APIEndpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: 46.31.96.42:18112
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "http://foo.com/sendMessage"
Content-Length: 1197

Max-Forwards: 10
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<sendMessage xmlns="http://foo.com/">
<NP_MESSAGE>
<ns1:HEADER xmlns:ns1="http://foo.com">
<REQUEST_ID xmlns="">NPMICL111103350390001
</REQUEST_ID>
<PROCESS_TYPE xmlns="">PORT</PROCESS_TYPE>
<MSG_TYPE xmlns="">Publish</MSG_TYPE>
<TRX_NO xmlns="">MI000004554248</TRX_NO>
<VERSION_NO xmlns="">1</VERSION_NO>
<RETRY_NO xmlns="">2</RETRY_NO>
<RETRY_DATE xmlns="">2011-11-03T13:00:06.659+02:00</RETRY_DATE>
<FROM xmlns="">MI</FROM>
<TO xmlns="">TZ</TO>
</ns1:HEADER>
<BODY xmlns="">
</BODY>
</NP_MESSAGE>
</sendMessage>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the exception im getting from the tomcat looks like this :

```
 03/11/2011 12:33:43 com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler invoke
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.foo.gw.ServiceApi.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:150)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:261)
```

and the tomcat returns : `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`

i notice that in the header the 
some parameters are missing between them but after reading some info i don't thing its the reason. beacose the request do get to the service in tomcat

UPDATE:
here is where i thing im getting the exception , i can't debug only scatter logs 
here is how my service class looks like :

UPDATE 2:
i know that the NP_MESSAGE is null but why i can see it get data when it comes from the client

```
@WebService (targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/")
public class Api {  
    Api()
    {

    }
    @WebResult(name="return_NP_ACK", partName="return_NP_ACK")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "sendMessage")
    public NPACK sendMessage(@WebParam(name = "NP_MESSAGE")NPMESSAGE NP_MESSAGE)
    {
    if(null != NP_MESSAGE)
{
    Logger.WriteLog("WebService NP_MESSAGE not null ",Level.DEBUG);


}
else
{
     //  I know that NP_MESSAGE is null im getting here !!!
    Logger.WriteLog("WebService NP_MESSAGE is null ",Level.DEBUG);
}
    HEADER hHeader = NP_MESSAGE.getHEADER();  <-- here is where the exception 
    ....
    ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE 3:
i found something but im not sure if its my case . and if it. how can i fix this . 
this is link that talks about [AX-RPC versus JAX-WS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc2/index.html) . i don't have the full knowledge if this is my case .
doesn't every WS framework suppose to always create stubs from wsdl that can talk no mater what did it , like contract like CORBA. never mine ..
any way how do i fix it , i don't have option to work with AXIS . can't i just tell JAXWS to work with the axis protocol ?

Comment: cant you run debug to see on which line NPE is thrown? to see what variable is null and why

Comment: I can just give advice about trying to use SOAP UI tool to have another independent client which can test call of your service. Either you configured it wrongly, or AXIS client calls it in a wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is here in the axis message:

```
<sendMessage xmlns="http://foo.com/">
<NP_MESSAGE>
```

because the xmlns definition defines the default namespace, the NP_MESSAGE element is now also defined in that namespace.  however, in the jaxws message, there is no default namespace, so the NP_MESSAGE element has *no namespace*.

you might try putting all your elements (WebParam, WebResult) in the same targetNamespace as your WebService.

Comment: Thanks for the response but now i see that there is no WebMethod annotation doesn't have the targetNamespace namespace parameter ...

Comment: just want you to know , that this was the solution ,Thanks!